# How to prevent extra spaces between two specific words when justification occurs?

Tags: spacing, tex-core, context

My document contains many short, justified lines, so the lines often appear with many spaces between words, e.g.:

```
These    words    have    a    space
so that they can fit nicely into the
available line.
```

In most situations, this is no problem, however, there are some select situations where I want a group of two or more words to appear together, even if other words in the lines are pulled apart, e.g., with "these words" linked:

```
These words     have     a     space
so that they can fit nicely into the
available line.
```

How can this be done?

I'm looking for either a ConTeXt or TeX solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`\hbox{These words}` will do. Or, if you prefer a macro,

```
\def\nespace{\hskip\fontdimen2\font\relax}
```

and

```
These\nespace words
```

This space has no stretch or shrink component, but is the same as the normal interword space. If you want to add shrinkability:

```
\def\nespace{\hskip\fontdimen2\font minus\fontdimen4\font\relax}
```

The main difference between the `\hbox` approach and `\nespace` is that a line break can be taken at `\nespace`. Shouldn't you want it, just add `\nobreak` before `\hskip` as glue is not a feasible break point if preceded by discardable items and `\nobreak` adds a penalty, which is discardable.

Comment: How about line breaks? Are they permitted at `\nespace`?

Comment: @lockstep Yes, of course: any glue is a feasible line break point if it's not preceded by discardable items. In order *not* to break, one can add `\nobreak` before `\hskip`.

Comment: In that case, please point out the difference to `\hbox` in your answer.