# Removing space between words when justified

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, width

I am writing a report and since the text is justified, every last sentence of a paragraph has more spaces between words in order to fit into the textwidth. I saw a lot of questions about this subject, I tried the solutions but it never worked for me. In addition to that, the solutions I've found may work for a countable number of words. However, I need to do it for all my report. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image]

In the picture above, there are two huge spaces between three words and I'd like to remove this, and to apply the solution for the whole document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide complete small code begging wit `\documentclass{...}` ending with `\end{document} which will generate text you show. Without this you left us to guessing ...

Comment: My crystal ball suggests `\break`. If so, please learn that you mark the end of a paragraph by a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a comparison of approaches:

1. using `\linebreak` at the end of a paragraph leads to the undesired large spacing between words that you discovered. Also the indentation of following paragraphs is missing.
2. using `\\` at the end of paragraphs does not give the large spaces between words, but the indentation of following paragraphs is still missing.
3. using `\\` in combination with a `\parskip` instead of an indentation will still give the wrong result as the `paskip` will be missing.
4. using an empty line inbetween paragraphs will give you the correct result in combination with paragraph indentations and ...
5. in combination with parskip.

Summary: The only correct way to separate paragraphs f text is an empty line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

\section{wrong result (large space between words) using linebreak command}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.\linebreak
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.\linebreak
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.


\section{wrong result (no paragraph indent on following paragraphs) using double backslash}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

\section{wrong result (no parskip between following paragraphs) using double backslash}
{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.}

\section{correct result (with paragraph indentation) using empty line}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

\section{correct result (with parskip) using empty line}
{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice comparison (+1). I'm afraid the OP is no longer active on site to accept the answer :-(

Comment: Related to the answer: 
Use **\hbox{** No additional space will be introduced between these words. **}**

[Credits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51882/how-to-prevent-extra-spaces-between-two-specific-words-when-justification-occurs)

Answer (score -2):

Actually I've found the answer thanks to @egreg. I've used `\linebreak` in the end of the line. But when I use `\\` instead, everything works fine.

Comment: You shouldn't use \\ either. End a paragraph with an empty line.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer okay thanks, but why shouldn't I use it?

Comment: You don't need it, and you will get lots of underfull box warnings in the log.

Comment: Furthermore, you won't have any `parindent` (if set to a non-zero value) for the paragraph that follows, since it won't be considered as such.

Comment: You can also use \par.